# Enhancing accuracy of knn classifier

Tags: matlab, knn

I have training set of size `54 * 65536` and a testing set of `18 * 65536`.

I want to use a knn classifier, but I have some questions:

1) How should I define `trainlabel`?

```
Class = knnclassify(TestVec,TrainVec, TrainLabel,k);
```

Is it a vector of size `54 * 1` that defines to which group each row in training set belongs? Here the group is numbered as 1 ,2,..

2) To find the accuracy I used this:

```
cp = classperf(TrainLabel);   
Class = knnclassify(TestVec,TrainVec, TrainLabel);
cp = classperf(TestLabel,Class);
cp.CorrectRate*100
```

Is this right? Is there another method to calculate it?

3) How can I enhance the accuracy?

4) How do I choose the best value of k?

Comment: please can any one help me? how to enhance accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know matlab nor the implementation of the knn you are providing, so I can answer only a few of your questions.

1) You assumption is correct. `trainlabel` is a `54*1` vector or an array of size 54 or something equivalent that defines which group each datapoint (row) in training set belongs to.

2) *... MATLAB / implementation related, sorry*.

3) That is a very big discussion. Possible ways are:

- Choose a better value of `K`.
- Preprocess the data (or make preprocessing better if already applied).
- Get a better / bigger trainset.

to name a few...

4) You can use different values while measuring the accuracy for each one and keep the best. (*Note: If you do that, make sure you do not measure the accuracy of the classifier per value of `k` only once, but rather you use some technique like **10-Folding** or something*).
There is more than a fair chance that the library you are using for the `K-NN`classifier provides such utilities.